# Assigning char array based on the value of char in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to assign a specific value of char array (or string) through conditionals depending on the value of char.

Suppose c is a char declared before the code with a specific value of some sort.

```
  char fruit[];
  if (c == 'R') {
    fruit[] = "Red";
  }
  else if (c == 'Y') {
    fruit[] = "Yellow";
  }
  else if (c == 'G') {
    fruit[] = "Green";
  }
  else if (c == "B") {
    fruit[] = "Blue";
  }
```

This code is obviously wrong but should give an idea on what I'm trying to do.

I am either planning to use a correct version of this for a simple program or have to go through around four times more conditionals to manually print the said string values which would be an immense pain.

Comment: `char fruit[];` and `fruit[] = "Red";` is not valid. You need to take `char *fruit` and then `fruit = "Red";` but this is string literal not modifiable. OR you can use `char fruit[100]` then `strcpy(fruit,"Red")`.

Comment: You can't *assign* to an array, but you can [*copy*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to it. However, then it needs to have a size of the largest data you want to copy to it (and for strings, don't forget the terminator).

Comment: `else if (c == "B")` is incorrect,also use `strcpy` for copying strings.

Answer (score 4):

```
  char *color;   // for modern compilers, should be  const char *color
  switch (c)
  {
  case 'R':    color = "Red";       break;
  case 'Y':    color = "Yellow";    break;
  case 'G':    color = "Green";     break;
  case 'B':    color = "Blue";      break;
  default:     color = "<unknown>"; break;
  }
```

I took exception at illogical variable names so renamed `fruit` to `color`, but this approach is one way to achieve what I think you are asking.

Comment: Sorry. Totally missed it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be to use a switch statement, but you'll first need to tell the compiler how big you want `fruit[]` to be, if you're not going to allocate it dynamically based on the character you detect.

Unless you're going to be dealing with fruits that have colors with *really* long names, I'd say 16 characters is enough for a demonstration. Hence:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fruity_printer(char c) {
    char fruit[16] = { 0 }; // initialize your arrays!
```

Now, a simple switch statement on char `c`

```
    switch (c) {
         case 'R':
            strcpy(fruit, "Red");
            break;
         // add more cases as needed

         default: // what happens if we don't have a case for it?
            strcpy(fruit, "Rainbow"); 
            break;
    }

    printf("The fruitabulous color is: %s\n", fruit);
    return;
    }
```

Note that I've used `strcpy()` here, because I'm *sure* that I know that I'll be writing within bounds of the destination. You'd never just arbitrarily copy something where the length wasn't known at compile time like that, you'd use `strncpy()` instead, which takes another argument for length.

Things you'll also want to do is convert `c` in the fruity printer  to either upper or lower, so you don't have to deal with both cases.

Another way would be to allocate your memory dynamically, but the semantics of figuring out what it should be are still best served by just using a simple switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch` case to that:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
      char c;
      char fruit[100];
      printf("Enter the character: ");
      scanf(" %c",&c);
      switch(c)
      {
          case 'R' : strcpy(fruit,"Red"); break; 
          case 'Y' : strcpy(fruit,"Yellow"); break; 
          case 'G' : strcpy(fruit,"Green"); break; 
          case 'B' : strcpy(fruit,"Blue"); break; 
          default : puts("No color");
      }
      printf("%s\n",fruit);
 }
```